# How do I code web forms that Mobile Safari will autofill?

Tags: mobile-safari

I haven't been able to find a tutorial for developers, just endless tutorials showing users how to turn the feature on via a Google search. Does anyone care to share how this was achieved? Here is a small example of my code..no autofill (yet). I do have my contact card filled out and the option turned on.

```
<div style='display:block;'> <
 <input name='first_name' id='firstName' type='text' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works if you wrap it with form tags. It's maddening that there isn't any documentation around this feature.